# Netbeans how to search for nested folder

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

Whenever I want to go to a nested folder, I have to manually expand all its parent folder to search for it (that is very unpleasant task). Is there a better way to search for nested folder in Netbeans or a keyboard shortcut to expand all folder within a project?

P/S: I'm using Netbeans-7.2.1 for PHP on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

`Alt + Shift + O` (Windows) is Quick open, for opening files. Just start typing the file name and a list of matches in all open projects will appear.

Comment: Alt + Shift + o just search for file NOT folder. Could u suggest another way. Notice that I'm working with Ubuntu 12.04 and Netbeans 7.2.1

Comment: Nope, the logic being that you can't do anything with a folder in Netbeans

Comment: Hi Daunhamzz, I see your point. Also, could you replace your answer with the comment to target my question more precisely. Then I can mark your answer as accepted one.